# Realm write transaction freezes the screen swift

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, ipad, realm

I am working on an application where I have to save images locally and I am using realm for this, the app takes let's say 10 to 40 images at a time from the gallery and start writing images to realm local database and freezes the screen during the writing process, plz how can I modify my code so that my app won't freeze during a write transaction, I am stuck in this situation, any help would be appreciated, thanks

```
let imagesAdd = refObject.1
let imageobjectArray = modelObject as! [FacilitiesImagesModel]
do{
    for imageObject in imageobjectArray{
         try realmObj.write {
              imagesAdd?.facilitiesImages.append(imageObject)
             }
     }
            
     completionHandler(true, "")
            
 }catch let err{
      realmObj.cancelWrite()
      completionHandler(false, err.localizedDescription)
 }
```

here is my full method, I have removed extra code that is not a part of my question

```
struct RealmCRUD {

private let realmObj = try! Realm()

func create<T>(modelObject: T, modelObjectType: ModelType, refObject: (PropertyModel?, FacilitiesModel?), completionHandler: @escaping ((Bool, String) -> Void)){
    
    switch modelObjectType {
        
    
        
    case .FacilitiesImagesModel:
        let imagesAdd = refObject.1
        let imageobjectArray = modelObject as! [FacilitiesImagesModel]
        do{
            for imageObject in imageobjectArray{
                try realmObj.write {
                    imagesAdd?.facilitiesImages.append(imageObject)
                    }
            }
            
            completionHandler(true, "")
            
        }catch let err{
            realmObj.cancelWrite()
            completionHandler(false, err.localizedDescription)
        }
        break
    }
    
    default:
    break
}
```

and I am calling this method from other classes like this:

```
func dismissComplete() {
    
    var arrayOfFacilitiesImagesModelObj = [FacilitiesImagesModel]()
    
    for photos in self.selectedAssets{
        
        if let photo = photos.fullResolutionImage{
            let facilitiesImagesModelObj = FacilitiesImagesModel()
            facilitiesImagesModelObj.facilityPhoto = photo.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5)!
            arrayOfFacilitiesImagesModelObj.append(facilitiesImagesModelObj)
        }else{
            print("Unable to select facility photos")
        }
        
    }
    
    self.realmCrudObj.create(modelObject: arrayOfFacilitiesImagesModelObj, modelObjectType: .FacilitiesImagesModel, refObject: (nil,self.realmFacilitiesResults), completionHandler: { (success, error)  in
        
        self.collectionViewReference?.reloadData()
    
        ProgressHUD.dismiss()
    
        if !success{
            self.showAlert(title: "Error", description: error)
        }
        })
}
```

and I am passing selected property data to this variable in this class

```
    var realmFacilitiesResults: FacilitiesModel?
```

here is my facility model

```
class FacilitiesModel: Object {

@objc dynamic var facilityName = ""

let facilitiesImages = List<FacilitiesImagesModel>()

let parentProperty = LinkingObjects(fromType: PropertyModel.self, property: "facilities")
```

}

Comment: It would be helpful if you were to share more code. You should show enough code so that we know what all of your variables and properties are. Perhaps share your model object definitions as well. What is modelObject? What is refObject? Etc.

Comment: Before we toss out some random solutions, more information is needed. Your question states that the UI freezes when writing 10 images - how large (Gb wise) are these images? Also, as @Rob mentions we need to see your Realm models to undersand exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: i have edited my question please check

Comment: @Jay no its normal images taken from camera

Comment: That's quite vague. 'normal images'? I have a 2 megapixel camera and you have a 20 megapixel camera - which one is 'normal'? I ask asking as the size of those images can play a major role in how you write the data and how the data is written.

Comment: average 2mb per image

Comment: @UmairKhan I'm curious to hear the advice that @Jay has for you. But the only other question I have is if your `realmFacilitiesResults` property is already managed by realm or if you still have to add it.

Comment: i am passing the realm results that i have queried
cell.realmFacilitiesResults = realmPropertyResults?[0].facilities[indexPath.row]
VARIABLE
private var realmPropertyResults: Results<PropertyModel>?
QUERY
realmPropertyResults = realmObj.objects(PropertyModel.self).filter("propertyName CONTAINS %@", name)

Comment: I just did some testing; I have 11 x 2Mb images loaded into an array. I then append them to a Realm object with a List property and write to disk. It takes approximately 1 second to do so. That being said, converting those images from .jpg to a Data object took way longer than writing them to disk. More importantly, Realm is NOT a good solution to store images - it's just not it's strong suit. You would be way better off leveraging something like [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage).

Comment: To clarify...Realm is not a good solution to store *large* images. Thumbnails and smaller sized pics (1Mb for example) work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is that you're doing multiple realm writes. You should be doing one realm write for all of your objects.

```
do {
    let realm = try Realm()
    try realm.write {
        imagesAdd?.facilitiesImages.append(objectsIn: imageobjectArray)
        completionHandler(true, "")
    } catch {
        print("realm write error: \(error)")
        completionHandler(false, "")
    }
}
```

If that still doesn't speed things up for you then you should add your objects to realm in a background thread. But because you'll be operating in a new thread you'll have to get thread-safe references.

```
let imageObjectsRefArray = imageObjectsArray.map { ThreadSafeReference(to: $0) }
let imagesAddRef = ThreadSafeReference(to: imagesAdd)
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "realm.image.add")
queue.async {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()
        guard let imagesAdd = realm.resolve(imagesAddRef) else {
            completionHandler(false, "")
            return
        }
        let imageObjectsArray = imageObjectsRefArray.compactMap { realm.resolve($0) }
        try realm.write {
            imagesAdd.facilitiesImages.append(objectsIn: imageObjectsArray)
        }
        completionHandler(true, "")
    } catch {
        print("realm write error: \(error)")
        completionHandler(false, "")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, now it saying: Argument type 'FacilitiesModel?' does not conform to expected type 'ThreadConfined'.

Here is my model:

class FacilitiesModel: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var facilityName = ""
    
    let facilitiesImages = List<FacilitiesImagesModel>()
    
    let parentProperty = LinkingObjects(fromType: PropertyModel.self, property: "facilities")
    
}

and I am creating variable like this:
var realmFacilitiesResults: FacilitiesModel?

Comment: @UmairKhan Hmm, it's probably complaining about your reference being an optional.

Comment: Brother its crashing with error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Cannot construct reference to unmanaged object, which can be passed across threads directly'

Comment: @UmairKhan Ah! I assumed that your objects were already stored in realm and that you were just establishing relationships. If your objects are not stored in realm then you don't need a thread safe reference. You can access them across different threads.

Comment: Which objects were unmanaged exactly? I'll update my answer when I have more info.

Comment: here is my method which i am calling when writing to realm:

func create<T>(modelObject: T, modelObjectType: ModelType, refObject: (PropertyModel?, FacilitiesModel?), completionHandler: @escaping ((Bool, String) -> Void)){
        
        switch modelObjectType {
        case .FacilitiesImagesModel:
            let imagesAdd = refObject.1
            let imageobjectArray = modelObject as! [FacilitiesImagesModel]
            ...

Comment: here is my model:
class FacilitiesModel: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var facilityName = ""
    
    let facilitiesImages = List<FacilitiesImagesModel>()
    
    let parentProperty = LinkingObjects(fromType: PropertyModel.self, property: "facilities")
    
}

Comment: @UmairKhan Please don't put code in comments - it's very hard to read.. Update your *question* with code.

Comment: oh sorry I am updating my question

Comment: @UmairKhan Also, before getting into Threadsafe references, (which are probably not needed for this use case) see the Realm Documentation on how to write data on a background thread. [Getting Started](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#getting-started) check out that first section of code, right where it says *// Query and update from any thread*. That's the code you want to use if writing data in the background.

Comment: @Jay Your referred link has solved my problem, thanks :)